# sending sms using pic16f877a and sim 300

Tags: sms, pic

Hi I have a problem in sending message in project, I am using pic16f877a and sim300. the main function runs repeatedly. Some characters are missed in the sent sms.
my program is like this...

```
void main()//main function
{ 
    Serial_init();  // initialization of serial communication
    Send_SMS();
}

void Serial_init()
{
    TRISC=0XC0; 
    TXSTA=0x24;
    SPBRG=129; // set baud rate 9600 Hz for 20MHz fosc
    RCSTA=0x90;
    TXIF=1;
}   

void Send_SMS(void)
{
    USART_puts("AT\0");
    putch1(0x0D);
    Delay_ms4M(200);
    USART_puts("AT+CMGF=1\0");       // switch into text mode

    putch1(0x0D);// ascii of Carriage Return
    Delay_ms4M(200);
    USART_puts("AT+CMGS=\"9741153218\"\0");   // send sms to the number
    putch1(0x0D);   
    Delay_ms4M(200);                            
    USART_puts("Hi this is working LOL\0"); // SMS text
    putch1(0x0A); // new line
    Delay_ms4M(200);
    putch1(0x0D);
    Delay_ms4M(100);
    putch1(0x1A);   // ascii of 'substitute' i.e end of file 
}


void USART_puts(const unsigned char *string)
{
    while(*string)
        putch1(*string++);
} 

void putch1(unsigned char data)
{
    while(TXIF==0);
    TXREG=data;
}
```

Please help

additional details: all other programs run properly, but if I call send_sms function, "main" runs repeatedly and several messages are sent with missed characters.

Comment: "but if I call send_sms function, "main" runs repeatedly ..."
You call send_sms and main is get called?... or you call main and it starts recursing? what is going on... Can you tell the problem clearly?

Comment: when the control is returned to 'main' from send_sms function, it starts from beginning  and send_sms is called again....

Comment: hi, can you put a your code for me. big help. im going to develop tracking system. your testing will help me lot. please. thanks. kasuninjava@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO :

**Your chip is resetting**. This is the highest probable cause.

Either it is **faulty** or you have set **Watchdog Timer** to **on** somewhere.

---

**For missing characters :**

a) Chip resets in the midst of a data transfer.

b) Roule of thumb for usart:

Stop stuffing bytes to usart. Send each byte with a small leading delay like 10-20 microseconds.

The communication is asynchronous, which means the receiver **has to synchronize** at the beginning of each *communication unit* which is a `byte`. To do that receiver brutely uses resources to detect start bit, the length (in time) of it etc. So if you try to send a byte train, you will stall the receiver.

---

Have you tried the code with **another** 16F877a ? (to check chip failure)...

Comment: Yup I have tried other programs the hardware is fine, only the function send_sms is troublesome.                                                                       thanks a lot... I will see about watch dog timer